# Can podcasts be grouped or organised in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, podcasts

I have a lot of podcast subscriptions in iTunes that cause a long scrollbar. This is exacerbated when a subscription is expanded and available podcasts listed.

It would be great if I could just group podcasts by type (eg, music, comedy, documentaries etc). I've been unable to find a way of doing this myself. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only way you can organize podcasts (and iTunes U content) is by title. These two libraries have different view settings than the others.